# Okta angular how to get token out of storage

Tags: angular, okta

I was playing with the Okta authentication library earlier today and I used the Angular 2 quickstart guide from their site: "https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/angular/dotnet/aspnetcore" and I got it in a sense that the browser has the cookie stored. However when I try to use: "oktaAuth.getAccessToken().accessToken " it gives amn error, also when I use "oktaAuth.getAccessToken()" it return an error.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { OktaAuthService, OktaAuthModule } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-list',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="messages.length">
      <li *ngFor="let message of messages"></li>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MessageListComponent {
  messages = [];
  constructor(private oktaAuth: OktaAuthService, private http: Http) {
    const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + oktaAuth.getAccessToken() });
    // Make request
    this.http.get(
      'http://localhost:58472/api/messages',
      new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
    )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((messages: Array<Object>) => messages.forEach(message => this.messages.push(message)));
  }
}
```

[image]

I have gone through the documentation many times but I can't seem to find any answer. Did anyone experience a similar issue? Any help will be much sppreciated, Cheers!

Comment: What error does `getAccessToken()` throw?

Comment: it gives an "undefined" error